# Stretch watermark from bottom left to top right on PDF c#

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

this might sound like a really simple question but I can not seem to figure it out.

I want to put a watermark on top of my PDF and need want it to start in the bottom left corner and end in the top right corner. My starting problem is that I can not  find the bottom left corner. I got a feeling that depending on the PDF document that I open the 0,0 coordinates change.

This is what I got so far:

```
 static string fontname = "Calibri";
        public void WaterMarkPDF3(string sourceFileName)
        {
            PdfDocument doc = PdfReader.Open(sourceFileName, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);

            foreach (PdfPage page in doc.Pages)
            {
                //First calculate the cross angle from bottom left to top right
                double Angle= -Math.Atan(page.Height / page.Width) * 180 / Math.PI;
                
                //here I calculate how long the diagonal is so that my string can have the same length
                double watermarkWidth = page.Height / Math.Sin(Angle);

                XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend);

                double emSize = 300;
                XFont font = new XFont(fontname, emSize, XFontStyle.Bold);
                XSize size = gfx.MeasureString("Teststring", font);

                gfx.TranslateTransform(page.Width / 2, page.Height / 2);
                
                gfx.RotateTransform(Angle);
                gfx.TranslateTransform(-page.Width / 2, -page.Height / 2);

                XGraphicsPath path = new XGraphicsPath();

                path.AddString("Teststring", font.FontFamily, XFontStyle.Bold, emSize,
                new XPoint(0, page.Height), XStringFormats.Default);

                // add to color to the outline and filling
                XPen pen = new XPen(XColor.FromArgb(75, 0, 152, 163), 2);
                XBrush brush = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(50, 0, 152, 163));

                gfx.DrawPath(pen, brush, path);

            }
            doc.Save(sourceFileName);
        }
```

By what I understand 0,0 would be the top left corner. Normaly if I start my watermark at `new XPoint(0, page.Height)` I expect it to be in the bottom left. Like you can see in the attached picture it comes at a "random" looking location.

[image: code result]

Comment: Could you please help us a bit by explaining maths you're using ? And would it be possible to have a screenshot of what your have so far ? I'll be glad to help you out.

Comment: also usually 0,0 is top left,I don't especially understand all your code since i never used this library, but it's an easy confusion since it's not the same as an usual math x,y coordinate. So you can check this out.

Comment: Check out here: http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=35&Itemid=46 about page size in pdfsharp

Comment: I have added some comments to the code to help explain the math. Something that also is not very clear to me is how to use the `emSize`. what I want to accomplish is that no matter what size of pdf gets uploaded it can place the watermark diagonally.

Comment: It sounds like an unclear question about a rather simple problem.

Comment: @JesuisMonica-Ihibernate what is unclear for you? I have added a picture with my code result. I would expect this to be a simple problem but I can not seem to control where the text starts.

Comment: The sample centers the watermark. Do you have reasons not to center the watermark? Parts of the string will be clipped when diagonal text starts exactly in the corner and it will be complicated to account for that. No clipping will occur with a centered string of reasonable length and size. Why do you rotate around the center of the page and not around the corner where you start the string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thank you all for the help.

I changed my text to an image (company logo). the code now works for all types of pages (A4, A3,....)

Code below:

```
public void WaterMarkPDF4(string sourceFileName)
        {
            PdfDocument doc = PdfReader.Open(sourceFileName, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);

            foreach (PdfPage page in doc.Pages)
            {
                double hoek = Math.Atan(page.Height / page.Width);
                double watermarkWidth = page.Height / Math.Sin(hoek);


                XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append);
                XImage image = XImage.FromFile(TransparentImage.png");

                double iWidth = image.PixelWidth * 72 / image.HorizontalResolution;
                double iHeight = image.PixelHeight * 72 / image.HorizontalResolution;
                double factor = watermarkWidth * 0.8 / iWidth;

                XPoint punt = new XPoint();
                punt.X = iWidth / 2;
                punt.Y = iHeight / 2;

                gfx.TranslateTransform(-iWidth / 2, -iHeight / 2);
                gfx.RotateAtTransform(-hoek * 180 / Math.PI, punt);
                gfx.ScaleAtTransform(factor,factor, iWidth / 2, iHeight / 2);


                double pwidth = page.Width;
                double pheight = page.Height;

                double dx = Math.Cos(hoek) * pwidth / 2 - Math.Sin(hoek) * pheight / 2;
                double dy = Math.Sin(hoek) * pwidth / 2 + Math.Cos(hoek) * pheight / 2;

                double newHeight = (image.PixelHeight / page.Width) * watermarkWidth;
                double y = page.Height/2  - newHeight / 2;


                gfx.DrawImage(image, dx/factor, dy/factor);

                gfx.Dispose();


            }
            doc.Save(sourceFileName);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Watermark sample can be found here:
https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp-samples/blob/master/samples/core/Watermark/Program.cs

One difference between the sample and your code is with `XStringFormat`. This defines how the string is aligned with respect to the given point. The sample simply aligns the center of the string with the center of the page.

Your "question" from the comments: `emSize` is the size of the font in points - 72 points are 1 inch. Your 300 points are 105.833 mm or 4.167 inches.

Your code snippet rotates around the center of the page. I presume this also changes the co-ordinates of the corner of the page. If you want to start the string  from the corner of the page then it is probably simpler to rotate around the corner of the page.
The sample draws the watermark at the center of the page and this is what most people will ask for.